# Conditional Formatting with user designed function

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

Overall my goal is to create a VBA macro that will go through a worksheet and apply a Conditional Formatting formula using a user designed function.  The worksheet is broken up into various groups that are each 31 rows, therefore I need to step based on 31 and set the conditional formatting.  I have created a custom function called `IdentifyFormulaCells` and that formula is used in the conditional formatting to do whatever color, text, etc.

```
Function IdentifyFormulaCells(rng As Range) As Boolean
'   Determine if cell contains a formula based on input range and returns True if there is a formula

IdentifyFormulaCells = rng.HasFormula

End Function

Sub LoopGroup()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iRng As Range
    Dim iStep As Long
    Dim ProjectRow As Long
    Dim FormulaString As String

    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim nCol As Long
    Dim nRow As Long

    Set rng = Range("I34:FH994")

    nCol = rng.Columns.Count
    nRow = rng.Rows.Count

'Sets the first project row
    ProjectRow = 34
    FormulaString = "=IdentifyFormulaCells(I" & CStr(ProjectRow) & ")"

'Based on number of employees listed per project
    iStep = 31

    For iRow = 1 To nRow Step iStep
        MsgBox "Project Row before action = " & ProjectRow
        MsgBox "FormulaString before action = " & FormulaString

        Set iRng = Range(rng.Cells(iRow, 1), rng.Cells(iRow, nCol))
        iRng.Select

        With Selection
            .FormatConditions.Delete

'THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS, NEED TO MAKE A FUNCTION OR STRING THAT INCREMENTS BASED ON THE PROJECT ROW BUT IT STOP AFTER THE FIRST GROUP

            '.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IdentifyFormulaCells(I34)"

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=FormulaString

        End With

        MsgBox "project row before step= " & ProjectRow
        ProjectRow = ProjectRow + iStep
        FormulaString = "=IdentifyFormulaCells(I" & CStr(ProjectRow) & ")"

    Next iRow

End Sub
```

If I comment out the `.FormatConditions.Add....` line then the code runs fine looping through each group of 31 rows, but as the code stands right now it stops after inputting the conditional formatting for only row 34.

Why does it enter only the first line?

Answer (score 0):

IF the objective is only to identify cells that contain formulae then it may be rather easier to:

Home > Editing > Find & Select - Go To Special..., Formulas and apply formatting of choice to the selected cells.